# Gitlab CI and matlab

Tags: matlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to set up some tests for a fairly large Matlab code I have on gitlab.

I created the .gitlab-ci.yml  file which launches a bash script that then calls matlab.

```
#.gitlab-ci.yml

before_script:

Test:
  script:
    - chmod +x RunTests.sh
    - ./RunTests.sh
```

The bash script is the following:

```
# RunTests.sh
cd IntegratedTests

LOGFILE=log.txt

matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -minimize -wait -logfile "$LOGFILE" -r 'RunTests';
CODE=$?

cat "$LOGFILE"

exit $CODE
```

However, gitlab tries to use the shared gitlab-runner which uses a docker image from ruby. The tests end ups failing because it cannot find matlab on the docker-image.

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.0.0-rc1 (58d8360f)
  on docker-auto-scale ed2dce3a
Using Docker executor with image ruby:2.5 ...
Pulling docker image ruby:2.5 ...
Using docker image sha256:80f53b90f8657c63c8d35d5eff399e6410baf19013c3b4c1c4158b2029060147 for ruby:2.5 ...
Running on runner-ed2dce3a-project-11747478-concurrent-0 via runner-ed2dce3a-srm-1561674473-a1c90512...
Fetching changes...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/darsim2simulator/darsim2/.git/
Created fresh repository.
From https://gitlab.com/darsim2simulator/darsim2
 * [new branch]      3-fixed-time-step-size -> origin/3-fixed-time-step-size
 * [new branch]      4-single-temperature-formulation-for-geothermal -> origin/4-single-temperature-formulation-for-geothermal
 * [new branch]      FIMLTS                 -> origin/FIMLTS
 * [new branch]      master                 -> origin/master
 * [new branch]      patch-1                -> origin/patch-1
 * [new branch]      patch-2                -> origin/patch-2
 * [new branch]      patch-3                -> origin/patch-3
Checking out ff3f0a4f as master...

Skipping Git submodules setup
$ chmod +x RunTests.sh
$ ./RunTests.sh
./RunTests.sh: line 6: matlab: command not found
cat: log.txt: No such file or directory
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I am guessing that the problem is that matlab is not installed on the docker-image

It's the first time I use the gilab CI so I may have not understood correctly how to use it but what are my alternatives? How can I set up a runner that has matlab?

Answer (score 0):

For specific runners in our project, I specify tags for a job in the `.gitlab-ci.yml`

Something like:

```
Test:
  script:
    - chmod +x RunTests.sh
    - ./RunTests.sh
  tags:
    - runners-tag
```

More info at

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#tags